# Regexp emoticons replacing fails with urls in string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Hello I'm creating a website in which I have a chat the user input is filtered for html entities and the only thing that is not escaped is links to images and website urls. Furthermore I have added some emoticons that are also being filtered out after the initial html encoding and this is the issue

I have a smiley with this key `":/": "sprite-uncertain"` inside my smileys object
which obviously conflicts with http://, ftp:// etc etc...

below is the code I'm using at the moment as a phase 2 encoding - replacement for the smileys:

```
var escapeRegExp = function( string ) {
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

var replaceAll = function( string, find, replace ) {
    return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'gi'), replace);
}   

var filterEmoticons = function( str ) {

    var emoticons = {
        "o:)": "sprite-angel",
        "&gt;:(": "sprite-angry",
        ":}": "sprite-aww",
        "^~^": "sprite-aww2",
        "{blush}": "sprite-blushing",
        ":&lt;": "sprite-childish",
        ":s": "sprite-confused",
        "{creepy}": "sprite-creepy",
        ":'(": "sprite-crying",
        "{cthulu}": "sprite-cthulhu",
        ":3": "sprite-cute",
        "{devil}": "sprite-devil",
        "&gt;_&lt;": "sprite-gah",
        "&gt;o&lt;": "sprite-gah2",
        ":o": "sprite-gasping",
        "$_$": "sprite-greedy",
        ":d": "sprite-grinning",
        ";d": "sprite-grinning-winking",
        ":&gt;": "sprite-happy",
        "&lt;:": "sprite-happy2",
        ":.": "sprite-happy3",
        "&lt;3": "sprite-heart",
        "o.O": "sprite-huh",
        "O.o": "sprite-huh2",
        ":*": "sprite-kiss",
        "{lol}": "sprite-laughing",
        "{lips}": "sprite-lips",
        "{mad}": "sprite-madness",
        "{malicious}": "sprite-malicious",
        "{sick}": "sprite-sick",
        ":)": "sprite-smiling",
        ":|": "sprite-speechless",
        "&gt;:)": "sprite-spiteful",
        "{stupid}": "sprite-stupid",
        "b)": "sprite-sunglasses",
        "d:": "sprite-terrified",
        "{win}": "sprite-thumb-up",
        "{fail}": "sprite-thumb-down",
        "-_-": "sprite-tired",
        ":p": "sprite-tongue-out",
        "xd": "sprite-tongue-out-laughing",
        ":b": "sprite-tongue-out-left",
        "p:": "sprite-tongue-out-up",
        "b:": "sprite-tongue-out-up-left",
        ";p": "sprite-tongue-out-winking",
        ":/": "sprite-uncertain",
        ":\\": "sprite-uncertain2",
        ":(": "sprite-unhappy",
        ";)": "sprite-winking",
        "x3": "sprite-x3",
        ";3": "sprite-cute-winking"
    };



    for ( var i in emoticons ) {
        str = replaceAll( str, i, '<em class="sprite '+emoticons[i]+'"></em>' );
    }

    return str;

}
```

I have to admit that I'm not the so good with regexp.
Is there a way to prevent replacement / encoding if ":/" is a part of a url?

Comment: You may want to just consider making it convenient for the user to turn automatic smiley replacement on and off. There are potential issues other than just URLs where replacement may be unwante **d:** (maybe they're using parenthetical asides to talk about bo **b)** .

Comment: you are correct haven't thought about that

Comment: You could add a character negation before the colon like `[^ps]`, which means that if the character before the `:` is a p or an s, it won't match, which will get rid of problems with `http://` and `https://`. Of course, you'd probably have to run a backreference on this, meaning it would become something like `"([^ps]):/": "$1sprite-uncertain"` (if that would work. I don't actually know for sure.)

Comment: This isn't very attractive, but here's one that will probably work: [/(\s|^):\/(\s|$)/](http://regex101.com/r/pA4qW1/1) (the link points to regex101 which allows you to test the regexp). It just checks if the previous character is whitespace or the beginning of the string and checks the same for the next character (for the end of string of course) and matches `:/` literally between.

Comment: Another solution would be to only allow smilies when they are surrounded by whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try. Some times when logical things does not work, we need to do some Tricks or use some quick fixes.

[js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYXLd/2/)

**Idea is:**

1) Add another phase, before **your phase 2 encoding - replacement for the smileys**. The phase is to mask the object which is adding trouble to your solution.

eg: convert **https://** to something which will not get matched when you are replacing smileys

```
k=$('#regex_string').val()

var mask_unmaskStringObj = {
    "https://":"httpsMask",
    "http://": "httpMask",
    "ftp://":"ftpMask"
}

for(each in mask_unmaskStringObj) {
    //match https://, http://, ftp:// etc
    //and replace to httpsMaskString, httpMaskString, ftpMaskString etc
    k = k.replace(new RegExp(each,'g'), function() {
        return mask_unmaskStringObj[each]
    })
}

$('#outputEn').val(k)
```

2) Replace your smileys - smoothly, without any issues of things like **https** because **now they don't have any conflicting string.**

3) **Reset** your masked string

```
for(each in mask_unmaskStringObj) {
    //Match httpsMaskString, httpMaskString, ftpMaskString etc
    //and replace it to match https://, http://, ftp:// etc
    k = k.replace(new RegExp(mask_unmaskStringObj[each],'g'), function() {
        return each
    })
}
```